# MPAndroidChart wrong highlighted value

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I have a barchart which x-axis goes from 0 to 11, inclusive.

I've added the `setOnChartValueSelectedListener` but the `highlight.getX()` returns 8, even if I click on the last bar, which should be 11.

What I'm doing:

1. Create a BarData object with a couple of entries - 1 per month basically, where the x value is the number of the month (0 to 11).
2. Set `setOnChartValueSelectedListener` on the chart
3. Run the app, horizontally scroll to the end of the chart, click the last bar

From what I read in the docs, this should trigger the listener with the highlighted/selected value, and when doing `entry.getX()` or `highlight.getX()` this should return 11, which was the clicked bar, but instead it returns 8. I'm not understand how the index is being selected.

For values [0-1] it reports *nothing selected*, for values [2-8] it reports the correct X value, and for values [9-11] it always reports 8 as the x value.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Elaborate more on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way the data was added to the `List<BarEntry>`. Make sure if it added in order.

If it's added, let's say, (x-value) 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3 then the selection will break like I described.